# SwiftUI - Pass variable from a TextField to a struct?

Tags: swiftui, struct, textfield

If I declare a variable:

```
@State var tiltAngle: Double = 0.0
```

And then bind it with a $ in a textfield

```
TextField("Tilt Angle", value: $tiltAngle, formatter: formatter)
```

If I want to use this value in a func it's available but how can I use this value in a struct? I need to use this value in the struct/Shape to calculate the angle to draw a line.

```
struct DrawPanel: Shape {
   let radians = 3.14159/180
   let tilt = cos(tiltAngle * radians)
   ...
}
```

This generates the "Cannot find 'tiltAngle' in scope" error. What's the correct approach?

Comment: How is DrawPanel related (in terms of view hierarchy) to the view with the text field?

Comment: They're all separate. How do you relate them?

Comment: Hi, are you able to add your full code for the draw panel? So I can recreate what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass `tiltAngle` to your `Shape` `struct`, declare `tiltAngle` as an `Angle` property without an initial value:

```
struct DrawPanel: Shape {
    let tiltAngle: Angle
    ...
}
```

When you use `DrawPanel`, pass the angle:

```
DrawPanel(tiltAngle: Angle(degrees: tiltAngle))
```

When you use the angle, you can extract the angle in radians:

replace your previous `tilt` with `cos(tiltAngle.radians)`

Take a look at how I handle `cornerRadius` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63650217/1630618).

Comment: This is the simpler solution, and similar to a Paul Hudson approach that I recently found. Many thanks to workingdog and vacawama.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, to use `tiltAngle` in a struct:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var tiltAngle: Double = 0.0
    
    @State var drawPanel = DrawPanel(tiltAngle: 0.0) // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Tilt Angle", value: $tiltAngle, formatter: NumberFormatter()).border(.red)
            .onSubmit {
                drawPanel = DrawPanel(tiltAngle: tiltAngle) // <-- here
            }
        Text("\(drawPanel.tilt)") // <-- here testing
    }
}

struct DrawPanel: Shape {
    let radians = 3.14159/180
    var tilt = 0.0
    
    init(tiltAngle: Double) {
        self.tilt = cos(tiltAngle * radians)  // <-- here
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return Path()  // <-- todo
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an elegant solution.